# React Native Dropdown Picker on Android pushes the other view down

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux

I am new in react native.

My question is pretty simple: I use package react-native-dropdown picker, but when I open the dropdown it push other View down. I think this problem is only on Android devices, not IOS.
Here is my code:

```
    <View style={[styles.filterCompany, Platform.OS !== 'android' ? { zIndex: 1 } : null]}>
                    <DropDownPicker
                        items={colleguesList}
                        open={showDropDown}
                        setOpen={() => setShowDropDown(!showDropDown)}
                        value={category}
                        setValue={value => setCategory(value)}
                        dropDownContainerStyle={{
                            width: 170,
                            alignSelf: 'center',
                            position: 'relative',
                            top: 0,
                            borderColor: Colors.SBLighBlue
                        }}
                        listMode="SCROLLVIEW"
                        style={{
                            width: 170,
                            height: 40,
                            alignSelf: 'center',
                            marginTop: 10,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.SBLighBlue,
                            borderColor: Colors.SBLighBlue
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
```

Here is image of problem:
[image]
Any suggestion how to solve?Thank you all :)

Comment: It might be happening due to `position: 'relative'` props. Use `position: 'absolute'` instead.

Comment: Yes its okay now, but I have new problem, when I click the option its click the avatar

Comment: If you still have the issue, try changing the zIndex of the view wrapping the dropdown picker to a higher value.